# Clicking submit button on form should take me to another page, but I stay on current page - Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to make a bot that automatically fills out [this form](https://amherstpp.ezlinksgolf.com/index.html#/preSearch) automatically.  I am using selenium with python, and I can get the script to populate the fields of the form correctly, but when I click on the search button, it doesn't bring me to the next page - it seems to just refresh the current page. I have tried filling out the form with the script and hitting the search button manually, but the same behavior is produced.  I have also tried using .click() and .submit() - no dice. Apologies if some of my code is messy as this is one of my first python scripts. Thanks!

```
# Tee  time booker
# This script books a tee time at ponemah greens

from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time

site = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

# user inputs
play_date="07/11/2021"
num_players=2


site.get("https://amherstpp.ezlinksgolf.com/index.html#/preSearch")

time.sleep(1)
title = site.title
assert "Amherst CC Prepaid - Online tee times made EZ" in title
dateField=site.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="dateInput"]')
dateField.clear()
dateField.send_keys(play_date)

time.sleep(1)
playerField=site.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="pc"]')
playerField.send_keys(num_players)

time.sleep(1)
courseSelector=site.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/ui-view/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/form/div/ul/li[4]/div/ul/li[2]/div/div[1]/input')
courseSelector.click()

time.sleep(1)
searchButton=site.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/ui-view/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/form/div/div/div/button')
searchButton.send_keys("\n")
print("Button Click")
```

Comment: when I run code then this page displays callendar and other elements are behide this callendar so they can't be cliecked/used - you have to close callendar before selecting course

Comment: some pages can recognize Selenium and block it.

Comment: I don't see anything really wrong with this (I don't believe you need the calls to `time.sleep`). It seems to take the form submission but then it returns a new form with the date and number of players filled in but no course selected. But if I add an `input('pausing...)` at the end and then after the new form is returned if I manually select a course and manually click on 'Search All', **it presents tee times** for me (I am using Chrome, too, but I have removed the code that  references `ChromeDriverManager().install()`). (...more)

Comment: If I insert `site.implicitly_wait(5)` followed by `elem = site.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/ui-view/div/div[1]/div[2]/nav/div[1]/div[2]/strong')` after the button is clicked, which looks for an element that exists on the tee times page, it *does not* throw a timeout exception. This means that it is transitioning to the tee times page but then immediately back putting out an empty form.

Comment: @booboo I also noticed that it flickers to the search results but then sends me back to the original page.  Do you think it is possible that the site is somehow detecting the use of Selenium and sending me back to the original form as furas mentioned?

Comment: Yes, it’s very possible. But why should I be able to get to the page by then manually clicking on the button with my mouse?

Comment: @JSacks Try with the `useragent. chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36")
site = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())`